# Node modules disappear after initializing the localy installed ESLint

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint

In my initial react application (created by `react-native init project_name`). In my project folder, I install my ESLint locally by `yarn add eslint --dev`.
Then I initialize my configuration by `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init` (with `Airbnb` style guide, using `React`, and `JSON` configuration file format). The installed eslint is disappeared in `./node_modules/.bin` folder.

Before initialization:

`ls ./node_modules/.bin
acorn           eslint          jest-runtime    node-pre-gyp    semver
atob            esparse         js-yaml         nopt            sshpk-conv
babylon         esvalidate      jsesc           pegjs           sshpk-sign
color-support   handlebars      json5           rc              sshpk-verify
detect-libc     image-size      loose-envify    react-native    uglifyjs
envinfo         import-local-fixture    metro   regjsparser     uuid
escodegen       is-ci           mime            rimraf          watch
esgenerate      jest            mkdirp          sane            which`

After initiliazation:

`ls ./node_modules/.bin
babylon     esparse     esvalidate  jsesc       loose-envify    semver`

What am I missing?

Platforms: macOS, react-native-cli: 2.0.1, react-native: 0.54.2

Comment: Almost certain I know what is causing this, but to confirm first, what version of npm do you have installed?

Comment: npm version is 5.6.0 @MichaelCheng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in NPM 5 where `npm install` will delete almost all of your dependencies. [This was the relevant issue.](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17929) Even though you are using `yarn`, `eslint` will use `npm` under the hood to install the dependencies it needs, and thus will run into the aforementioned bug.

This has very recently been fixed in **npm >= 5.7.1**, so you will need to upgrade `npm` and then reinstall all of your modules.

*Personally, I'd just recreate the entire project from scratch since it doesn't seem like you've done anything yet. It would be a lot more straightforward than trying to fix things.*

By upgrading, you will also be able to use `react-native-cli` without error as prior to v5.7.1, you were actually supposed to use NPM 4. [See this bug.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14767)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and the excellent clarification of the reasons laying behind.