# React Native: NPM Module being uninstall each time a new is installed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, node-modules

I am using a package named `react-native-linear-gradient` which can be found [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient). I had to go through quite a lengthy process to eventually get the link to my project (by manually linking via the `Binary link with libraries` in XCode. I got it working fine, however, each time I install a new package via NPM, `linear-gradient` is removed from my node-modules folder.

1.Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening? (Happy to provide additional information)
2.Will this impact deployment of the application if this is not solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node modules disappear after initializing the localy installed ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437590/node-modules-disappear-after-initializing-the-localy-installed-eslint)

Comment: Just a shot in the dark since I don't have a computer on hand to try and reproduce the issue. See if that helps.

Comment: @MichaelCheng Hi, i've recently upgraded NPM to `5.8.0`, being the latest version

Comment: Very interesting. I haven't looked at the 5.8.0 release notes but I'll be doing so now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Downgraded to `5.7.1`... It seems `5.8.0` seems to cause the same [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437590/node-modules-disappear-after-initializing-the-localy-installed-eslint) Michael mentioned.